# How to get the CPU MHz (in /proc/cpuinfo) by the syscall?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, system-calls

In the `/proc/cpuinfo`, I find a strange parameter "cpu MHz" which is changing all the time. I want to study how it works. Does there exist some syscall that can help me get this parameter? I wish this syscall can help me know how to calculate the cpu MHz.

Comment: "I wish this syscall can help me know how to calculate the cpu MHz." - For that purpose you may check implementation of `/proc/cpuinfo` file instead. As other files in `/proc` filesystem this file is implemented inside the kernel.

Comment: `open` and `read` are syscalls.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no syscall that will tell you the current speed (MHz) of your CPU. If you want to know the value without writing a kernel module for it, you can read the `/proc/cpuinfo` file, which is there exactly for this purpose (making this info available to user space programs). There also is [a good post here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837545/how-to-know-cpu-frequency) which lists more ways to obtain such information.

If you want to know how the values are calculated you can look at the source code of the Linux kernel. In particular, [the `fs/proc/cpuinfo.c` file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/fs/proc/cpuinfo.c) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

you might find the information in the `/sys` filesystem easier to parse:

```sh
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:900014
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:900016
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:883064
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:862357
```

under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/` you will find more interesting properties of each CPU on your system, all of them in an easy-to-parse format (usually just a single line)